# Android Use SimpleDateFormat

Tags: android

I get a data from server like this:

```
data = "2015-04-24T23:00:17+08:00"
```

I am in UTC+8,I want get

```
data = "2015-04-24 23:00:17"
```

I program this

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
Data = formatter.parse(data);
```

But I get that

```
Fri Apr 24 23:00:17 格林尼治标准时间+0800 2015
```

How can I correct it?

if I use

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-M-dd HH:mm:ss",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

I get

```
Fri Apr 24 23:00:17 GMT+08:00 2015
```

It is not I want

Comment: Try `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you parse the date you returned from server, you have a java.util.Date object. If you want to convert to your own format you have to again format the date object.

```
private String getDate(String serverDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat serverFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
    try {
        Date date = serverFormatter.parse(serverDate);

        SimpleDateFormat myFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        String formattedDate = myFormatter.format(date);

        return formattedDate;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `Locale`.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale)).

Answer (score 0):

For your desired output you need to change the date format to

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```